# Интерфейс или абстрактный класс?

Tags: java, интерфейс, класс

У меня такой вопрос. Часто задают вопрос, а что лучше использовать абстрактный класс или интерфейс? А я хочу и то и другое сразу.
У меня есть сущность, которая является абстрактной и имеет 2 метода, которые будут реализованы в наследниках, но которые имеют базовую реализацию и переменные нестатические, которые будут задействованы в этих методах. А также у меня есть интерфейс с теми же самыми методами.
Я хочу взять этот абстрактный класс и реализовать в нем интерфейс с теми же самыми методами. Чтоб потом в системе обращаться к таким сущностям через интерфейс, а не абстрактный класс.
Так можно делать? Какие проблемы меня могут ждать в будущем или это идеальное решение?
Если сказать о задаче в целом, то у меня будут события от разных источников и разные обработчики для каждого источника. Вот для базового обработчика и используется абстрактный класс, который реализует интерфейс.
А потом уже будут реальные обработчики для каждого типа события.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это реализовать?
Задача вроде типовая.

Comment: Смотря что и зачем, я уже давно на Java не писал и теперь лучше разбираюсь в другом языке. Поэтому ответ будет скорее всего субъективный и неполный. Почему бы не "и то и другое", выстроив иерархию так: `Интерфейс -> Абстрактный класс -> Реализация`. Тогда методы будут иметь реализацию по-умолчанию, а экземпляры могут быть переданы везде, где принимается интерфейс. Все зависит от конкретных целей, мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Обращение к сущностям через интерфейс - идеальное решение.
Проблемы могут возникнуть, если не использовать интерфейс.

Пользователям интерфейса должны быть неинтересными детали реализации: сколько есть классов, реализующих данный интерфейс, и как они между собой связаны.

Если же в программе упоминается конкретный класс, реализующий интерфейс, то впоследствии возникнут проблемы при необходимости что-то сделать с этим классом.

Comment: Да, я знаю, что лучше программировать от интерфейсов. Но я это читала, когда у нас есть интерфейс и его реализация без абстрактных классов. Здесь с абстрактным классом тоже надо всегда программировать от интерфейсов? И почему тогда на собеседованих спрашивают, что лучше абстрактный класс или интерфейс использовать? Какие проблемы могут возникнуть в будущем, если оставить один абстрактныц класс

Comment: Не будет потом путаницы, что где-то мы где-то пишем в коде интерфейс, а где-то абстрактный класс, а где-то и то и другое?

Comment: @Галина а в чем будет путаница-то? Они не являются взаимоисключающими. Если вы используете интерфейсы, то это не значит, что вы теперь не можете использовать абстрактные классы, и наоборот. Советую почитать про отличие абстрактных классов и интерфейсов, вопрос о том, что лучше, отпадет сразу, т.к. у них разное назначение

Comment: А когда мы пишем класс который реализует этот абстрактный класс, надо ещё добавлять имплемент интерфейса?

Comment: То есть exampleClass extends abstractExampleClass implement example interface. Хотя abstractExampleClass уже реализует этот интерфейс?

Comment: @Галина нет, не нужно

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!